# setting JaxbAnnotationIntrospector causes an error

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson

I create a custom object mapper which extends ObjectMapper. I set the introspector:

```
public CustomObjectMapper()
    {
        super();
        AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(getTypeFactory());
        setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
    }
```

And get the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value: method <init>()V not found
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:85)
    at com.company.project.client.jackson.CustomObjectMapper.<init>(CustomObjectMapper.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 38 more
```

Everything worked fine until I updated Jackson from 2.0.1 to 2.4.5. Why do I get that error and how to set AnnotationIntrospector in Jackson 2.4?

UPDATE. Changing libraries to 2.4.0 solved the problem.

Comment: Which Jackson libs are you using? Did you upgrade all of them?

Comment: jackson-core-2.4.5, jackson-databind-2.4.5, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.4.5, jackson-annotations-2.4.0

Comment: I changed everything to 2.4.0 and and seems to work now

Comment: As a general rule, one should use same minor version of all Jackson components. And since new features are added in minor versions, dependencies must be so that minor version of something component depends on is at least same as component itself. In your case `jackson-databind` had later version (2.4), but had earlier version of `jackson-annotations` that it depends on; this meant it was missing a class that it was relying on (being compiled against 2.4).

Comment: Thank you! I used gradle to add libraries, do not know why it chose 2.4.0 for annotations, I set everything to 2.4.5.